# avoid span to cut/new line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I've came across this bad looking spans, when I resize my window to a small one. In the code example I defined a `width:20px;` just to prove that my span "cut" into a newline, which I dont want. Is there a way to avoid this?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table style="width:20px;">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">
      <div class='row ml-1'>          
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span title='Passed' class='bg-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2'>
              54 passed
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span title='failed' class='bg-danger rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2'>
              54 failed
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span title='error' class='bg-warning rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2'>
              54 error
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span title='notRun' class='bg-primary rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2'>
              54 not run
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a `d-inline-block` that fixes the issue.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table style="width:20px;">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">
      <div class='row ml-1'>          
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span title='Passed' class='bg-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2 d-inline-block'>
              54 passed
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span title='failed' class='bg-danger rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2 d-inline-block'>
              54 failed
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span title='error' class='bg-warning rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2 d-inline-block'>
              54 error
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span title='notRun' class='bg-primary rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2 d-inline-block'>
              54 not run
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `white-sapce: nowrap` to the span, if you want to prevent the breaks

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table style="width:20px;">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">
      <div class='row ml-1'>          
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span  style="white-space: nowrap" title='Passed' class='bg-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2'>
              54 passed
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span style="white-space: nowrap" title='failed' class='bg-danger rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2'>
              54 failed
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span title='error' class='bg-warning rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2'>
              54 error
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <span style="white-space: nowrap" title='notRun' class='bg-primary rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-2'>
              54 not run
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: whats best `d-inline-block` or `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup or not a table of 20px of width ?  ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus He explained, that he only added the 20px for demonstration reasons.

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup I don't know it there is a "best" solution, but`white-space: nowrap` is a more general approach, it basically tells the line to never break. If you are ok with the line break, the bootstrap class also works, and is maybe even more flexible, if there are large numbers or long labels.